# Dell XPS8100 Wont boot windows 7 - Error 0x0000007b & error code 0142

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, windows-xp, boot

The computer froze and when restarted would not boot to windows 7. Several of the files start to load but when it gets to the AVG virus software it freezes. When I turn on the machine, the 'windows error recovery' screen pops up followed by files being loaded then the blue screen without icons appears.

I have tried all options on the F8 screen but nothing works (all 3 safe modes, repair your computer, enable boot logging, enable low resolution video, last know good configure, debugging mode, directory services restore mode). Nothing on the F8 screen is working.

After I tried all options above, the Windows logo and 'starting windows' appears but then goes to the "Boot Screen" with the F2 & F12 Options and then goes to windows recovery error screen. Windows files start to load and then goes to the blue screen.
I have tried to load the operating system but that gives me the 0x0000007b error.

I removed one of the memory chips but that didn't work. I tried a windows 98 boot disk and could get to the DOS prompt but was unable to create a temp registry.

Any guidance is appreciated. I'd like to use the new hard drive and recover the data from the old hard drive.

I ran a test and received the following 2 error codes
0F00: 133C - No suitable disk media present 
0F00: 065D Disk - DST Self-test Read error
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you had blue screen, according to my experience you must choose 'safe mode' after entering BIOS and uninstall the last program or suspicious program.if it doesn't work maybe you must re install windows. this link maybe helpfull :
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/0f00-133c-error-code-no-suitable-disk-or-media-is/66dcc559-bd4f-4b70-a39e-0dfd7669d596